# Disable search in some files

Tags: xcode, search

my project is quite big - consists of 122 .h+.m files has in the resources about 200 plist files. When I try to search (cmd+shift+f) the results appear very slowly. Can I speed this process a little bit? Can I give some instructions to Xcode to skip searching the plist files?

Regards
Chris